# SQL having equivalent keyword in ES query DSL

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following query to be converted to DSL and executed on ES. I could not find a suitable aggregation and filter over results of aggregation available out-of-the-box in ES. As an alternative, I am fetching the 'group by count' for each id from ES and filtering the result as a part of my application logic, which is not efficient. Can you suggest any more suitable solution?

```
select distinct id from index where colA = "something" group by id having count(*) > 10;
```

**index mapping**
id : (string)
colA: (string)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html): to get distinct Ids.
2. [Bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html): to return ids with doc count more than 10

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "colA.keyword": "something" --> where clause
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_id": {
      "terms": {                         --> group by
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids_having_count_morethan_10": {
          "bucket_selector": {            --> having
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.count>10"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```